# duplicates in oracle query

Tags: mysql, oracle

I have the following query to get duplicate ssn's and the count of duplicates. But there is a probability where same ssn is used for different login_ids in the same table.

```
Select distinct SOCIALSECURITY, count(*) from PROCESS 
WHERE SOCIALSECURITY IS NOT NULL and PROCESS_NAME = 'NEW_ACCOUNT'
GROUP BY SOCIALSECURITY HAVING COUNT(SOCIALSECURITY) > 1;
```

What I am looking for is to get the Login_id which used the same SOCIALSECURITY and how many times it used.

for example : LOGIN_ID, SSN, PROCESS_NAME

```
john123 | 123-45-7890 | 'NEW_ACCOUNT'
john123 | 123-45-7890 | 'NEW_BUSINESS'
johnbaker123 | 123-45-7890 | 'NEW_ACCOUNT'
zeechan | 647-000-0000 | 'NEW_ACCOUNT'
```

I want to get the result like

```
123-45-7890 | 2
```

Comment: If you use the condition `and PROCESS_NAME = 'NEW_ACCOUNT'` in your query, You can never get result as `123-45-7890 | 2` for same LOGINID. Are you sure you have to use this condition in your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I see it, it is `count(distinct login_id)` you're looking for.

```
SQL> with test (login_id, ssn, process_name) as
  2    (select 'john123'     , '123-45-7890', 'NEW_ACCOUNT'  from dual union all
  3     select 'john123'     , '123-45-7890', 'NEW_BUSINESS' from dual union all
  4     select 'johnbaker123', '123-45-7890', 'NEW_ACCOUNT'  from dual union all
  5     select 'zeechan'     , '647-00-0000', 'NEW_ACCOUNT'  from dual
  6    )
  7  select ssn, count(distinct login_id) cnt
  8  from test
  9  group by ssn
 10  having count(*) > 1;

SSN                CNT
----------- ----------
123-45-7890          2

SQL>
```

Comment: yes, I got what I needed in a different way. this query is returning users with 1 login_id for the same ssn too, not just ssn's with 1 login_id.. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query -

```
SELECT SOCIALSECURITY, count(*)
  FROM PROCESS 
 WHERE SOCIALSECURITY IS NOT NULL
   AND PROCESS_NAME = 'NEW_ACCOUNT'
 GROUP BY LOGIN_ID, SOCIALSECURITY
HAVING COUNT(SOCIALSECURITY) > 1;
```

Comment: This query is returning all the duplicates by SOCIALSECURITY but not by both SOCIALSECURITY and login_id like how I wanted..